# igraph python summary not working as expected

Tags: python, igraph

I would like to use the `summary()` functions in python-igraph, as it seems very helpful to understand the initial structure of a network, but something doesn't seem right.

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Nexus.get("karate")
igraph.summary(g)
IGRAPH UN-- 34 78 -- Zachary's karate club network
+ attr: Author (g), Citation (g), name (g), Faction (v), id (v), name (v)
```

From all the examples I've seen, I see people getting back to following information from `summary()`, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
>>> g = Graph.Tree(127, 2)
>>> summary(g)
127 vertices, 126 edges, undirected
Number of components: 1
Diameter: 12
Density: 0.0157
Average path length: 8.3510
```

Maybe I'm missing something with the newest version of igraph?

Comment: I don't know where the second output is coming from, but it is surely not from igraph.

Comment: @GaborCsardi  -  I came across the igraph summary second output example here: http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: That's outdated, here is the new version: http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get information like Number of components, Diameter,Density and
Average path length, you should do something like the following:

```
from igraph import *

g=Graph.Tree(127,2)
print(g.diameter())
print(g.average_path_length())
print(g.density())
print(g.components())
```

The result is :

```
>>> 12

>>> 8.3509

>>> 0.015

>>> Clustering with 127 elements and 1 clusters
```